# feign client returns exception for multipart request

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a service which has a controller with the responsability of sending an email with attachment. This endpoint is consumed by another microservice using feign-client.

```
@RequestMapping("/email")
public class EmailNotificationController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sendEmail(
        @RequestPart("sendEmailRequest") SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest,
        @RequestPart(name = "attachment", required = false) MultipartFile attachment) {
    }
}
```

Below is the implementation of the feign client which fails at runtime.

```
import com.oceanobe.timesheet.timesheetservice.dto.request.SendEmailRequest;
import feign.Headers;
import feign.RequestLine;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
@FeignClient(value = "NOTIFICATION-SERVICE/notificationservice")

public interface NotificationServiceFeignClient {

    @RequestLine("POST /email")
    @Headers({"{Content-Type: multipart/form-data}"})
    void sendEmail(@RequestPart("sendEmailRequest") SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest,
        @RequestPart("attachment") String attachment
    );
```

It fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.oceanobe.timesheet.timesheetservice.service.feign.NotificationServiceFeignClient': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract void com.oceanobe.timesheet.timesheetservice.service.feign.NotificationServiceFeignClient.sendEmail(com.oceanobe.timesheet.timesheetservice.dto.request.SendEmailRequest,java.lang.String)
Warnings:
- Class NotificationServiceFeignClient has annotations [FeignClient] that are not used by contract Default
- Parameter sendEmailRequest has annotations [RequestPart] that are not used by contract Default
- Parameter attachment has annotations [RequestPart] that are not used by contract Default
```

how the endpoint looks from postman perspective:
[image]

I dont know why it fails with the error from above.